# How to package pytest python file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pytest, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package and run a pytest file on a computer that doesnt have Python and pytest installed.

I'm trying to go about this using pyinstaller which says it can do pytest, but cannot find any examples of how to go about this.

Any ideas how I can use pyinstaller to package the python headers and the pytest headers to simulate calling "py.test filename.py"  without the need to install pytest?

Comment: Why are you trying to test Python code (implied by the fact that you're using `pytest`) on a machine without Python?  PyInstaller is typically used for distributing production software, which shouldn't have dependencies on `pytest`.  I feel like this is an XY problem:  *what are you really trying to do*?

Comment: To purpose if for convenience and because it can be done. Pyinstaller claims "Fortunately recent PyInstaller releases already have a custom hook for pytest". But when i build my code, i get ImportError: No module named 'py._builtin'